# Nextcloud server side encryption

Tags: encryption, nextcloud

Does anyone know whicj encryption algorithm is used in server side encryption on Nextcloud v12 ?

Thanks for you answer

Comment: Odds on guess is AES. Why are you interested?

Answer (score 0):

As @zaph already mentioned correctly, it is AES-256-CTR.